# pandas unique values multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Bill', 'Mary', 'Joe'],
                   'Col2': ['Joe', 'Steve', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Steve'],
                   'Col3': np.random.random(5)})
```

What is the best way to return the unique values of 'Col1' and 'Col2'?

The desired output is

```
'Bob', 'Joe', 'Bill', 'Mary', 'Steve'
```

Comment: See also [unique combinations of values in selected columns in pandas data frame and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268817/unique-combinations-of-values-in-selected-columns-in-pandas-data-frame-and-count) for a different but related question. The selected answer there uses `df1.groupby(['A','B']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})`

Answer (score 293, accepted):

[`pd.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.unique.html) returns the unique values from an input array, or DataFrame column or index.

The input to this function needs to be one-dimensional, so multiple columns will need to be combined. The simplest way is to select the columns you want and then view the values in a flattened NumPy array. The whole operation looks like this:

```
>>> pd.unique(df[['Col1', 'Col2']].values.ravel('K'))
array(['Bob', 'Joe', 'Bill', 'Mary', 'Steve'], dtype=object)
```

Note that `ravel()` is an array method that returns a view (if possible) of a multidimensional array. The argument `'K'` tells the method to flatten the array in the order the elements are stored in the memory (pandas typically stores underlying arrays in [Fortran-contiguous order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26999092/3923281); columns before rows). This can be significantly faster than using the method's default 'C' order.

---

An alternative way is to select the columns and pass them to [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
>>> np.unique(df[['Col1', 'Col2']].values)
array(['Bill', 'Bob', 'Joe', 'Mary', 'Steve'], dtype=object)
```

There is no need to use `ravel()` here as the method handles multidimensional arrays. Even so, this is likely to be slower than `pd.unique` as it uses a sort-based algorithm rather than a hashtable to identify unique values.

The difference in speed is significant for larger DataFrames (especially if there are only a handful of unique values):

```
>>> df1 = pd.concat([df]*100000, ignore_index=True) # DataFrame with 500000 rows
>>> %timeit np.unique(df1[['Col1', 'Col2']].values)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.12 s per loop

>>> %timeit pd.unique(df1[['Col1', 'Col2']].values.ravel('K'))
10 loops, best of 3: 38.9 ms per loop

>>> %timeit pd.unique(df1[['Col1', 'Col2']].values.ravel()) # ravel using C order
10 loops, best of 3: 49.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: How do you get a dataframe back instead of an array?

Comment: @Lisle: both methods return a NumPy array, so you'll have to construct it manually, e.g., `pd.DataFrame(unique_values)`. There's no good way to get back a DataFrame directly.

Comment: @Lisle since he has used pd.unique it returns a numpy.ndarray as a final output. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: @Lisle, maybe this one df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['C1','C2','C3'])?

Comment: To get only the columns you need into a dataframe you could do df.groupby(['C1', 'C2', 'C3']).size().reset_index().drop(columns=0). This will do a group by which will by default pick the unique combinations and calculate the count of items per group The reset_index will change from multi-index to flat 2 dimensional. And the end is to remove the count of items column.

Answer (score 17):

I have set up a `DataFrame` with a few simple strings in its columns:

```
>>> df
   a  b
0  a  g
1  b  h
2  d  a
3  e  e
```

You can concatenate the columns you are interested in and call `unique` function:

```
>>> pandas.concat([df['a'], df['b']]).unique()
array(['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'h'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This doesn't work when you have something like this `this_is_uniuqe = {
    'col1': ["Hippo", "H"],
    "col2": ["potamus", "ippopotamus"],
}
`

Answer (score 12):

```
In [5]: set(df.Col1).union(set(df.Col2))
Out[5]: {'Bill', 'Bob', 'Joe', 'Mary', 'Steve'}
```

Or:

```
set(df.Col1) | set(df.Col2)
```

Answer (score 9):

An updated solution using numpy v1.13+ requires specifying the axis in [np.unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) if using multiple columns, otherwise the array is implicitly flattened.

```
import numpy as np

np.unique(df[['col1', 'col2']], axis=0)
```

This change was introduced Nov 2016: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/1f764dbff7c496d6636dc0430f083ada9ff4e4be

Answer (score 4):

for those of us that love all things pandas, apply, and of course lambda functions:

```
df['Col3'] = df[['Col1', 'Col2']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

here's another way

```py
import numpy as np
set(np.concatenate(df.values))
```

Answer (score 2):

Non-`pandas` solution: using set().

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Bill', 'Mary', 'Joe'],
              'Col2' : ['Joe', 'Steve', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Steve'],
               'Col3' : np.random.random(5)})

print df

print set(df.Col1.append(df.Col2).values)
```

Output:

```
   Col1   Col2      Col3
0   Bob    Joe  0.201079
1   Joe  Steve  0.703279
2  Bill    Bob  0.722724
3  Mary    Bob  0.093912
4   Joe  Steve  0.766027
set(['Steve', 'Bob', 'Bill', 'Joe', 'Mary'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Bill', 'Mary', 'Joe'],
               'Col2': ['Joe', 'Steve', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Steve'],
               'Col3': np.random.random(5)})
```

If your question is how to get the unique values of each column individually?

Sort the column labels in a list

```
column_labels = ['Col1', 'Col2']
```

Create an empty dict

```
unique_dict = {}
```

Iterate over selected columns to get their unique values

```
for column_label in column_labels: 
    unique_values = df[column_label].unique()
    unique_dict.update({column_label: unique_values})
unique_ser = pd.Series(unique_dict)
print(unique_ser)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stack` to combine multiple columns and `drop_duplicates` to find unique values:

```
df[['Col1', 'Col2']].stack().drop_duplicates().tolist()
```

Output:

```
['Bob', 'Joe', 'Steve', 'Bill', 'Mary']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list(set(df[['Col1', 'Col2']].as_matrix().reshape((1,-1)).tolist()[0]))
```

The output will be
['Mary', 'Joe', 'Steve', 'Bob', 'Bill']

Comment: `DataFrame` object has no attribute `as_matrix`.

Comment: Depending on which version you are using. Please see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of unique values given a list of column names:

```
cols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']
unique_l = pd.concat([df[col] for col in cols]).unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @Mykola Zotko's answer using `stack` and `unique` is the most intuitive to me:

```py
df[['Col1', 'Col2']].stack().unique()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'col1':["a","a","b","c","c","d"],'col2': 
                ["x","x","y","y","z","w"],'col3':[1,2,2,3,4,2]})
df
```

output is

```
  col1 col2 col3
0   a   x   1
1   a   x   2
2   b   y   2
3   c   y   3
4   c   z   4
5   d   w   2
```

to get the unique values from all the columns

```
    a={}
    for i in range(df.shape[1]) :
        j=df.columns[i]
        a[j] = df.iloc[:,i].unique()

   for p,q in a.items():
       print( f"unique value in {p} are {list(q)} ")
```

ouput is

```
    unique value in col1 are ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
    unique value in col2 are ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'] 
    unique value in col3 are [1, 2, 3, 4]
```