# unique combinations of values in selected columns in pandas data frame and count

Tags: python, pandas

I have my data in pandas data frame as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['yes','yes','yes','yes','no','no','yes','yes','yes','no'],
                   'B':['yes','no','no','no','yes','yes','no','yes','yes','no']})
```

So, my data looks like this

```
----------------------------
index         A        B
0           yes      yes
1           yes       no
2           yes       no
3           yes       no
4            no      yes
5            no      yes
6           yes       no
7           yes      yes
8           yes      yes
9            no       no
-----------------------------
```

I would like to transform it to another data frame.  The expected output can be shown in the following python script:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'A':['no','no','yes','yes'],'B':['no','yes','no','yes'],'count':[1,2,4,3]})
```

So, my expected output looks like this

```
--------------------------------------------
index      A       B       count
--------------------------------------------
0         no       no        1
1         no      yes        2
2        yes       no        4
3        yes      yes        3
--------------------------------------------
```

Actually, I can achieve to find all combinations and count them by using the following command: `mytable = df1.groupby(['A','B']).size()`

However, it turns out that such combinations are in a single column.  I would like to separate each value in a combination into different column and also add one more column for the result of counting.  Is it possible to do that?  May I have your suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

You can `groupby` on cols 'A' and 'B' and call `size` and then `reset_index` and `rename` the generated column:

```
In [26]:

df1.groupby(['A','B']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
Out[26]:
     A    B  count
0   no   no      1
1   no  yes      2
2  yes   no      4
3  yes  yes      3
```

**update**

A little explanation, by grouping on the 2 columns, this groups rows where A and B values are the same, we call `size` which returns the number of unique groups:

```
In[202]:
df1.groupby(['A','B']).size()

Out[202]: 
A    B  
no   no     1
     yes    2
yes  no     4
     yes    3
dtype: int64
```

So now to restore the grouped columns, we call `reset_index`:

```
In[203]:
df1.groupby(['A','B']).size().reset_index()

Out[203]: 
     A    B  0
0   no   no  1
1   no  yes  2
2  yes   no  4
3  yes  yes  3
```

This restores the indices but the size aggregation is turned into a generated column `0`, so we have to rename this:

```
In[204]:
df1.groupby(['A','B']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

Out[204]: 
     A    B  count
0   no   no      1
1   no  yes      2
2  yes   no      4
3  yes  yes      3
```

`groupby` does accept the arg `as_index` which we could have set to `False` so it doesn't make the grouped columns the index, but this generates a `series` and you'd still have to restore the indices and so on....:

```
In[205]:
df1.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False).size()

Out[205]: 
A    B  
no   no     1
     yes    2
yes  no     4
     yes    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Note: as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364400/1224158, you could substitute `count()` instead of `size()` to both ignore NaN and return a dataframe

Comment: Maybe a bit clearer: right after `size()`, use `rename("count")`.
So, the Series produced by `size()` now have `name` attribute set to "count", and the `name` attribute will be the column name of the DataFrame produced by `reset_index()`.

Comment: if you would like to avoid explicitly listing the column names and are interested in grouping all columns, you could do instead: `df1.groupby(list(df1.columns))`

Comment: With a recent pandas version (>= 1.1.0), Mykola Zotko's answer is much more readable: `df.value_counts` now does this out of the box.

Answer (score 45):

In Pandas 1.1.0 you can use the method [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) with DataFrames:

```
df.value_counts() # or df[['A', 'B']].value_counts()
```

Result:

```
A    B
yes  no     4
     yes    3
no   yes    2
     no     1
dtype: int64
```

Convert index to columns and sort by value counts:

```
df.value_counts(ascending=True).reset_index(name='count')
```

Result:

```
     A    B  count
0   no   no      1
1   no  yes      2
2  yes  yes      3
3  yes   no      4
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the accepted answer and @Bryan P's comment relating to the differences between [count() and size()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364400/1224158), I opted for count() for cleaner code as below :

```
df1.groupby(['A','B']).count().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly related, I was looking for the unique combinations and I came up with this method:

```
def unique_columns(df,columns):

    result = pd.Series(index = df.index)

    groups = meta_data_csv.groupby(by = columns)
    for name,group in groups:
       is_unique = len(group) == 1
       result.loc[group.index] = is_unique

    assert not result.isnull().any()

    return result
```

And if you only want to assert that all combinations are unique:

```
df1.set_index(['A','B']).index.is_unique
```

Comment: Didn't know about `set_index()`. Kept trying to use `groupby()` for grouping together rows with a particular common pair of columns. Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done time test with this but it was fun to try.  Basically convert two columns to one column of tuples.  Now convert *that* to a dataframe, do 'value_counts()' which finds the unique elements *and* counts them.  Fiddle with zip again and put the columns in order you want.  You can probably make the steps more elegant but working with tuples seems more natural to me for this problem

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'A':['yes','yes','yes','yes','no','no','yes','yes','yes','no'],'B':['yes','no','no','no','yes','yes','no','yes','yes','no']})

b['count'] = pd.Series(zip(*[b.A,b.B]))
df = pd.DataFrame(b['count'].value_counts().reset_index())
df['A'], df['B'] = zip(*df['index'])
df = df.drop(columns='index')[['A','B','count']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Placing @EdChum's very nice answer into a function `count_unique_index`.
The unique method only works on pandas series, not on data frames.
The function below reproduces the behavior of the [unique](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/unique) function in R:

> unique returns a vector, data frame or array like x but with duplicate elements/rows removed.

And adds a count of the occurrences as requested by the OP.

```
def count_unique_index(df, by):                                                                                                                                                 
    return df.groupby(by).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})                                                                                                      

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['yes','yes','yes','yes','no','no','yes','yes','yes','no'],                                                                                             
                    'B':['yes','no','no','no','yes','yes','no','yes','yes','no']})   
                                                                                                                                                                                 
count_unique_index(df1, ['A','B'])                                                                                                                                              
     A    B  count                                                                                                                                                                  
0   no   no      1                                                                                                                                                                  
1   no  yes      2                                                                                                                                                                  
2  yes   no      4                                                                                                                                                                  
3  yes  yes      3
```