# How to obtain all unique combinations of values of particular columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract all unique combinations of values of columns `Col1`, `Col2` and `Col3`. Let's say there is the following dataframe `df`:

```
df =

Col1    Col2    Col3
12      AB      13
11      AB      13
12      AB      13
12      AC      14
```

The answer is:

```
unique =

Col1    Col2    Col3
12      AB      13
11      AB      13
12      AC      14
```

I know how to obtain unique values of a particular column, i.e. `df.Col1.unique()`, however not sure about unique combinations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding unique combinations of columns from a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110156/finding-unique-combinations-of-columns-from-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a method for this - [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates()
   Col1 Col2  Col3
0    12   AB    13
1    11   AB    13
3    12   AC    14
```

You can do it `inplace` as well:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
>>> df
   Col1 Col2  Col3
0    12   AB    13
1    11   AB    13
3    12   AC    14
```

If you need to get unique values of certain columns:

```
>>> df[['Col2','Col3']].drop_duplicates()
  Col2  Col3
0   AB    13
3   AC    14
```

as @jezrael suggests, you can also consider using `subset` parameter of `drop_duplicates()`:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Col2','Col3'])
   Col1 Col2  Col3
0    12   AB    13
3    12   AC    14
```

Comment: What if I can much more columns? I only need to get unique values of three columns. Should it be something like this?: `df[["Col1","Col2","Col3"]].drop_duplicates()`

Comment: @RomanPekar - I think OP wants `print (df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Col1','Col2','Col3']))`

Comment: @jezrael I think he needs to get only unique values of certain columns, but I'll add your suggestion to the answer, thanks

Comment: @RomanPekar - Yes, but if there is multiple columns and need only filter by 3 columns, need subset. But it depends what OP exactly need.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `unique()` method on the index:

```
index = ['Col2','Col3']
df.set_index(index).index.unique().to_frame(False)
```

And you might be interested in knowing the number of time each combination is repeated using `value_count` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67883591/2641825)

```
df[index].value_counts()
```