# Finding unique combinations of columns from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In my below data set, I need to find unique sequences and assign them a serial no ..

DataSet :

```
user    age maritalstatus   product
A   Young   married 111
B   young   married 222
C   young   Single  111
D   old single  222
E   old married 111
F   teen    married 222
G   teen    married 555
H   adult   single  444
I   adult   single  333
```

Expected output:

```
young   married     0
young   single      1
old     single      2
old     married     3
teen    married     4
adult   single      5
```

After finding the unique values like shown above, if I pass a new user like below,

```
user age maritalstatus  
X     young  married
```

it should return me the products as a list .

```
X : [111, 222]
```

if there is no sequence, like below

```
user     age     maritalstatus  
    Y     adult  married
```

it should return me an empty list

```
Y : []
```

Comment: `Young` and `Single` is `young` and `single` ? Or need lowercase?

Comment: look also at wes mckinney's [blog entry](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/filtering-out-duplicate-dataframe-rows/)

Comment: looking out for some serious help on this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First select only columns for output and add [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), last add new column by `range`:

```
df = df[['age','maritalstatus']].drop_duplicates()
df['no'] = range(len(df.index))
print (df)
     age maritalstatus  no
0  Young       married   0
1  young       married   1
2  young        Single   2
3    old        single   3
4    old       married   4
5   teen       married   5
7  adult        single   6
```

If want convert all values to lowercase first:

```
df = df[['age','maritalstatus']].apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).drop_duplicates()
df['no'] = range(len(df.index))
print (df)
     age maritalstatus  no
0  young       married   0
2  young        single   1
3    old        single   2
4    old       married   3
5   teen       married   4
7  adult        single   5
```

EDIT:

First convert to `lowercase`:

```
df[['age','maritalstatus']] = df[['age','maritalstatus']].apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())
print (df)
  user    age maritalstatus  product
0    A  young       married      111
1    B  young       married      222
2    C  young        single      111
3    D    old        single      222
4    E    old       married      111
5    F   teen       married      222
6    G   teen       married      555
7    H  adult        single      444
8    I  adult        single      333
```

And then use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for unique `product` converted to `list`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'user':'X', 'age':'young', 'maritalstatus':'married'}])
print (df2)
     age maritalstatus user
0  young       married    X

a = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['age','maritalstatus'])['product'].unique().tolist()
print (a)
[111, 222]
```

---

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'user':'X', 'age':'adult', 'maritalstatus':'married'}])
print (df2)
     age maritalstatus user
0  adult       married    X

a = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['age','maritalstatus'])['product'].unique().tolist()
print (a)
[]
```

But if need column use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['prod'] = df.groupby(['age', 'maritalstatus'])['product'].transform('unique')
print (df)
  user    age maritalstatus  product        prod
0    A  young       married      111  [111, 222]
1    B  young       married      222  [111, 222]
2    C  young        single      111       [111]
3    D    old        single      222       [222]
4    E    old       married      111       [111]
5    F   teen       married      222  [222, 555]
6    G   teen       married      555  [222, 555]
7    H  adult        single      444  [444, 333]
8    I  adult        single      333  [444, 333]
```

EDIT1:

```
a = (pd.merge(df, df2, on=['age','maritalstatus'])
       .groupby('user_y')['product']
       .apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())
       .to_dict())
print (a)
{'X': [111, 222]}
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.merge(df, df2, on=['age','maritalstatus']))
  user_x    age maritalstatus  product user_y
0      A  young       married      111      X
1      B  young       married      222      X
```

Comment: whats `user_y` ??

Comment: For me `pd.merge(df, df2, on=['age','maritalstatus'])` return `user_x` and `user_y`, so was used `user_y`.

Comment: @pylearner - I edit answer , there are in putput 2 columns for users `user_x` and `user_y` what is used for build dictionary.

Comment: for my dataframe, in `user_y`, I  have multiple users matching ... its throwing me an error

Comment: I have idea, give me sec

Comment: @pylearner - Can you check `a = pd.merge(df[['age','maritalstatus', 'product']], df2, on=['age','maritalstatus']).groupby('user')['product'].apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).to_dict()` ?

Comment: can you help on this ....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124436/selecting-only-required-keys-from-a-dictionary-using-a-dataframe

Comment: Jez, can we modify the above code ? I have millions of customers and its throwing a memory error

Comment: @pylearner - Unfortunately in pandas it is not easy :( I think problem is your data are really large and small RAM of your PC. Solutions are 3 - add RAM(practically very often problematic), use `dask`, `blaze` or some another technology, or processes data by chunks (e.g. by 500MB), drop duplicates for each chunk and last concat output.

Comment: @pylearner - Aslo you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas)

Comment: hey if I pass the same user A in my DF2 in the above, it should return me [222] as he has already purchased [111] .. can we achieve this ?

Comment: @pylearner - Not sure if understand, can you create new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128817/grouping-data-using-unique-combinations

Comment: it is almost the same as yesterday

Comment: are you looking into it ?

Comment: @pylearner - I check it, really complicated. I need more time.

Comment: @pylearner - I start working with it. But dont understand `A: [222] - as user A has already purchased 111` - Why? Because in second DataFrame is no information about `product`. Can you explain more?

Comment: If I pass the information of user A again, generally it will output `A: [111,222]`,  as per the code you provided above. But what I want is, as A already has product 111 in the dataframe, the age and marital status is matching with `user B`.. so it should return only `[222]`

Comment: New one, if this can be done... we can ignore the earlier one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130520/subtracting-values-of-a-list-in-a-dictionary-using-a-dataframe

Comment: Jez, i had a memory error and was not able to merge... please look into this question. Help me out :( ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137714/assign-the-values-which-are-not-present-already-in-the-column

Comment: I guess you are sleeping ?

Comment: @pylearner - now I check my phone, but I  am offline with PC. Allen solution failed? Is neccesary something else? Tomorrow I try help, but this is not easy, unfortu.ately :(

Comment: yes this code `a = pd.merge(df[['age','maritalstatus', 'product']], df2, on=['age','maritalstatus']).groupby('user')['product'].apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).to_dict()` gives me memory error. Please try and help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way is `pd.factorize`. Note I convert columns to lower case first for results to make sense.

```
for col in ['user', 'age', 'maritalstatus']:
    df[col] = df[col].str.lower()

df['category'] = list(zip(df.age, df.maritalstatus))
df['category'] = pd.factorize(df['category'])[0]

#   user    age maritalstatus  product  category
# 0    a  young       married      111         0
# 1    b  young       married      222         0
# 2    c  young        single      111         1
# 3    d    old        single      222         2
# 4    e    old       married      111         3
# 5    f   teen       married      222         4
# 6    g   teen       married      555         4
# 7    h  adult        single      444         5
# 8    i  adult        single      333         5
```

Finally, drop duplicates:

```
df_cats = df[['age', 'maritalstatus', 'category']].drop_duplicates()

#      age maritalstatus  category
# 0  young       married         0
# 2  young        single         1
# 3    old        single         2
# 4    old       married         3
# 5   teen       married         4
# 7  adult        single         5
```

To map a list of products, try this:

```
s = df.groupby(['age', 'maritalstatus'])['product'].apply(list)
df['prod_catwise'] = list(map(s.get, zip(df.age, df.maritalstatus)))
```

Another option is to use [categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), which I highly recommend for workflows. You can easily extract codes from a categorical series via `pd.Series.cat.codes`.