# grouping data using unique combinations

Tags: python, pandas

n my below data set, I need to find unique sequences and assign them a serial no ..

DataSet :

```
user    age maritalstatus   product
A   Young   married 111
B   young   married 222
C   young   Single  111
D   old single  222
E   old married 111
F   teen    married 222
G   teen    married 555
H   adult   single  444
I   adult   single  333
```

unique sequence:

```
young   married     0
young   single      1
old     single      2
old     married     3
teen    married     4
adult   single      5
```

After finding the unique values like shown above, if I pass a dataframe like below,
newdataframe

```
user    age maritalstatus  
A      Young   married 
X      young   Single  
D      old     single  
Z      old     married
```

it should return me the products as a list .

```
A: [222] - as user A has already purchased 111, the matching sequence contains 222, so returns 222.
X: [111, 222]
D: [] - returns nothing, as there is only one sequence like this, and D has already purchased the product 222, so returns empty.
Z: [111] matches with sequence E, so returned 111
```

if there is no sequence, like below

```
user     age     maritalstatus  
    Y     adult  married
```

it should return me an empty list

```
 Y : []
```

Comment: I did it with a new user x...

Comment: @pyleaner  in that case post your code

Answer (score 0):

you can use sets - module that provides classes for constructing and manipulating unordered collections of unique elements

have a look:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html