# subtracting values of a list in a dictionary using a dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe below, with the products purchased by users.

DataSet :

```
user    age maritalstatus   product
A   Young   married 111
B   young   married 222
C   young   Single  111
D   old single  222
E   old married 111
F   teen    married 222
G   teen    married 555
H   adult   single  444
I   adult   single  333
```

dictionary:

```
{A:[111,222], B:[111,222], C:[111], D:[222], G:[222,555], X:[222,444] }
```

Expected output:

```
{A:[222], B:[111], C:[], D:[], G:[222], X:[222,444] }
```

The  dictionary should look into the dataframe and remove the products already purchased by the users.

Comment: The solution is precisely what you think it is. You will need to iterate. Tried anything?

Comment: I havent tried anything ...

Comment: I was suppose to use it in a different way, but that dint seem to work, so changed it entirely and came to this

Comment: G shouldn't have 555 in result, right?

Comment: Yes, @jpp..Thanks I edited

Comment: @pylearner, A piece of friendly advice. Since you are learning python, a good exercise would be to compare the below solutions and understand how they relate. Otherwise, just running our code won't help you with your next problem.

Comment: Thanks @jpp ... ill take your words

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
{k:[e for e in v if e not in df.loc[df.user.eq(k), 'product'].tolist()] for k,v in d.items()}
Out[292]: {'A': [222], 'B': [111], 'C': [], 'D': [], 'G': [222], 'X': [222, 444]}
```

A slightly more verbose solution for easier understanding:

First to build a user-product dict:

```
user_prod = df.groupby('user')['product'].apply(list).to_dict()
{'A': [111],
 'B': [222],
 'C': [111],
 'D': [222],
 'E': [111],
 'F': [222],
 'G': [555],
 'H': [444],
 'I': [333]}
```

Then, use a dict comprehension to remove elements which are in the user_prod dict.

```
{k:[e for e in v if e not in user_prod.get(k,[])] for k,v in d.items()}
Out[319]: {'A': [222], 'B': [111], 'C': [], 'D': [], 'G': [222], 'X': [222, 444]}
```

The use of user_prod.get is necessary because the user may not exist and .get will avoid an exception by returning an empty list.

Comment: @jpp, thanks for the comment and I've added a slightly more verbose answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one intuitive way to implement your logic. You can optimize via sets and comprehensions, but for reasonable size datasets the below method should be adequate.

```
products = df.groupby('user')['product'].apply(list)

d = {'A':[111,222], 'B':[111,222], 'C':[111], 'D':[222], 'G':[222,555], 'X':[222,444] } 

for k, v in d.items():
    p = products.get(k)
    if p:
        for i in p:
            d[k].remove(i)

# {'A': [222], 'B': [111], 'C': [], 'D': [], 'G': [222], 'X': [222, 444]}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   product  user
0        1    10
1        2    11
2        1    12
3        1    13
4        2    14

new_purchase = frame.set_index('user')['product'].to_dict()
```

> ```
> {10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 2}
>
> {10: [2, 1], 11: [2], 12: [], 13: [22], 14: [1]}
> ```

```
result = {}
        for k, v in prev_purchase.items():
            result[k] = [item for item in v if item not in [new_purchase[k]]]
```

> {10: [2], 11: [], 12: [], 13: [22], 14: [1]}