# Using transform to add a count of duplicate rows on certain columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have looked through various SO questions solving the problem of counting duplicate rows on specific columns, most relevant is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268817/unique-combinations-of-values-in-selected-columns-in-pandas-data-frame-and-count) one.

The thing is, that this solution is very specific and I can't figure out how to generalize it to dataframes with many more data.
I have a dataframe that has many columns, and I want to add a new column named 'A_D_E_count' that will indicate how many rows in the entire dataframe have the same value of A, D and E columns of each row.

Preferably this should work using `.transform` function

Example:

```
Out[6]: 
      A        B        C        D        E
0   294    41981    37597    39875    33364
1   294    39776    37597    37572    39171
2   294    44658    49408    43713    49408
3   294    58615    52065    43713    49408
4   294    44811    51238    42926    49408
```

Over this dataframe, I would like to add a column that will count number of rows containing the same `A` `D` and `E` values so the result would be

```
Out[6]: 
      A        B        C        D        E  A_D_E_count
0   294    41981    37597    39875    33364            1
1   294    39776    37597    37572    39171            1
2   294    44658    49408    43713    49408            2
3   294    58615    52065    43713    49408            2
4   294    44811    51238    42926    49408            1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need `size` or `count` if dont need count `NaN`s with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
cols = ['A','D','E']

df['A_D_E_count'] = df.groupby(cols)['A'].transform('size')
print (df)
     A      B      C      D      E  A_D_E_count
0  294  41981  37597  39875  33364            1
1  294  39776  37597  37572  39171            1
2  294  44658  49408  43713  49408            2
3  294  58615  52065  43713  49408            2
4  294  44811  51238  42926  49408            1
```