# Nested for loops for Large Datasets using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, nested-loops, code-complexity

I am working on a data analysis and I have to generate Histograms. My code has more than 7 nested for-loops. Each nested loop filters the data frame by a unique value from the category to form a new data frame of sub categories and then splitting further like previous. Each day has around 400,000 records. And I have to process last 30 days record. The result is to produce histograms for the values(only one numerical column) of the last un-splittable category. How do I reduce complexity? Any alternate methods ?

```
for customer in data_frame['MasterCustomerID'].unique():
    df_customer = data_frame.loc[data_frame['MasterCustomerID'] == customer]
    for service in df_customer['Service'].unique():
        df_service = df_customer.loc[df_customer['Service'] == service]
        for source in df_service['Source'].unique():
            df_source = df_service.loc[df_service['Source'] == source]
            for subcomponent in df_source['SubComponentType'].unique():
                df_subcomponenttypes = df_source.loc[df_source['SubComponentType'] == subcomponent]
                for kpi in df_subcomponenttypes['KPI'].unique():
                    df_kpi = df_subcomponenttypes.loc[df_subcomponenttypes['KPI'] == kpi]
                    for device in df_kpi['Device_Type'].unique():
                        df_device_type = df_kpi.loc[df_kpi['Device_Type'] == device]
                        for access in df_device_type['Access_type'].unique():
                            df_access_type = df_device_type.loc[df_device_type['Access_type'] == access]
                            df_access_type['Day'] = ifweekday(df_access_type['PerformanceTimeStamp'])
```

Comment: Can you provide some of the data please?

Comment: I wouldn't assume that you're not a `pandas` expert, but one of the purposes of the `pandas` package is specifically to avoid `for` loops

Comment: Sorry! It's a corporate's private data. That would be security breach.

Comment: Okay I have added the code I need solution for

Comment: You can use the Pandas very own routines `groupby` and  `filter` to do your job in a vectorized manner.

Comment: You can use `zip()` on multiple lists so that you only have one loop.

Comment: @p-robot These aren't multiple lists.. these are lists derived from previous loop

Comment: @akshay-murali, You can subset on lists of unique values from the complete dataframe, simply include a condition to check if the resultant dataframe is empty or not.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.groupby` to find unique combinations of different levels of the columns (see [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27405483/how-to-loop-over-grouped-pandas-dataframe) and [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/35268817/unique-combinations-of-values-in-selected-columns-in-pandas-data-frame-and-count#35268906)) and then loop over the dataframe grouped by each combination.  There are ~4000 combinations so be careful when uncommenting the histogram code below.

```
import string
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(100)

# Generate 400,000 records (400 obs for 1000 individuals in 6 columns)
NIDS = 1000; NOBS = 400; NCOLS = 6

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 4, size = (NIDS*NOBS, NCOLS)))
mapper = dict(zip(range(26), list(string.ascii_lowercase)))
df.replace(mapper, inplace = True)

cols = ['Service', 'Source', 'SubComponentType', \
    'KPI', 'Device_Type', 'Access_type']
df.columns = cols

# Generate IDs for individuals
df['MasterCustomerID'] = np.repeat(range(NIDS), NOBS)

# Generate values of interest (to be plotted)
df['value2plot'] = np.random.rand(NIDS*NOBS)

# View the counts for each unique combination of column levels
df.groupby(cols).size()

# Do something with the different subsets (such as make histograms)
for levels, group in df.groupby(cols):
    print(levels)

    # fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # ax.hist(group['value2plot'])
    # ax.set_title(", ".join(levels))
    # plt.savefig("hist_" + "_".join(levels) + ".png")
    # plt.close()
```