# Pandas - Extract unique column combinations and count them in another table

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

**TASK 1:**

I have table like this:

```
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------+
| a_name_0 | id_qname_0 | a_name_1 | id_qname_1 | a_name_2 | id_qname_2 | count |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------+
| country  | 1          | NAN      | NAN        | NAN      | NAN        | 100   |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------+
| region   | 2          | city     | 8          | NAN      | NAN        | 20    |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------+
| region   | 2          | city     | 9          | NAN      | NAN        | 80    |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------+
| region   | 3          | age      | 4          | sex      | 6          | 40    |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------+
| region   | 3          | age      | 5          | sex      | 7          | 60    |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------+
```

I need to turn each row in series, drop NANs and convert series in a dictionaries which will be variable in size, for example, first 2 dicts will look like this:

```
{'a_name_0':'country','id_qname_0':1}
{'a_name_0':'region','id_qname_0':2, 'a_name_1':'city','id_qname_1':8}
{'a_name_0':'region','id_qname_0':2, 'a_name_1':'city','id_qname_1':9}
```

Each dictionary after that should be stored in a list.

**TASK 2.**

Using table below I have to count appearance of columns from dict from previous step:

```
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
| id       | country    | city     | age        | sex      | 
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
| 1        | 1          | NAN      | NAN        | NAN      | 
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
| 2        | 1          | 8        | NAN        | NAN      | 
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

If there is some faster mapping solution please advise since what I'm about to do is probably going to be quite messy. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262355/identify-unique-combinations-of-values-in-columns-sum-another-column-and-count) answer doesn't help me since I need iterator for extracting parameters as well as counting their appearance.

Comment: How are extracted `id` for second `DataFrame` ?

Comment: @jezrael ´id´ is irrelevant. I only need to scan if columns from dict are present in row and count them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove `count` column and convert all rows to list of dicts by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='r'` (`records`) and then filter out dicts with missing values in dictionary comprehension:

```
L = [{k:v for k, v in x.items() if pd.notna(v)} for x in df.drop('count', 1).to_dict('r')]
print (L)
[{'a_name_0': 'country', 'id_qname_0': 1},
 {'a_name_0': 'region', 'id_qname_0': 2, 'a_name_1': 'city', 'id_qname_1': 8.0}, 
 {'a_name_0': 'region', 'id_qname_0': 2, 'a_name_1': 'city', 'id_qname_1': 9.0}, 
 {'a_name_0': 'region', 'id_qname_0': 3, 'a_name_1': 'age', 
 'id_qname_1': 4.0, 'a_name_2': 'sex', 'id_qname_2': 6.0},
 {'a_name_0': 'region', 'id_qname_0': 3, 'a_name_1': 'age',
 'id_qname_1': 5.0, 'a_name_2': 'sex', 'id_qname_2': 7.0}]
```

Not 100% sure for second DataFrame:

```
L1 = [dict(zip(list(x.values())[::2], list(x.values())[1::2])) for x in L]
df = pd.DataFrame(L1)
print (df)
   country  region  city  age  sex
0      1.0     NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
1      NaN     2.0   8.0  NaN  NaN
2      NaN     2.0   9.0  NaN  NaN
3      NaN     3.0   NaN  4.0  6.0
4      NaN     3.0   NaN  5.0  7.0
```

Comment: nice, better than my solution `for index, row in df.drop('count',axis=1).iterrows():
    list_.append(row.dropna().to_json(orient='index'))`

Comment: @Datanovice list comprehension is way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2119941 but I'll take any solution that works since this is not big data case. Thank you Jozef my friend! You did it again ;)