# return a unique pair of columns in python regardless of the order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['yes','yes','yes','yes','no','no','yes','yes','yes','no'],
                   'B':['yes','no','no','no','yes','yes','no','yes','yes','no']})

df
----------------------------
index         A        B
0           yes      yes
1           yes       no
2           yes       no
3           yes       no
4            no      yes
5            no      yes
6           yes       no
7           yes      yes
8           yes      yes
9            no       no
-----------------------------
```

The ideal output would be like:

```
----------------------------
          A       B       
----------------------------
0         no       no           
1        yes       no       
2        yes      yes      
----------------------------
```

Instead of having four combinations of `yes` and `no`, there are only 3 combos, so `yes no` and `no yes` will be the same pair, the frequency of each pair doesn't really matter.

I've tried using `groupby` but obviously it will give you 4 pairs, I've also tried `pd.unique`. Very similar problem to [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268817/unique-combinations-of-values-in-selected-columns-in-pandas-data-frame-and-count), but not entirely the same, and I borrowed the example from there. Thanks yall!

Comment: `df[['A','B']].drop_duplicates` ?

Comment: Sort along the first axis, drop duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df,axis=1),columns =df.columns ).drop_duplicates()
```