# Python Pandas: How to find patterns of combinations (Combinations of Combinations) - time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations, permutation

Started from here: [unique combinations of values in selected columns in pandas data frame and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268817/unique-combinations-of-values-in-selected-columns-in-pandas-data-frame-and-count)

I have found the most to least occurring combinations of 3 columns with this code:

```
def common_cols(df,n):
    '''n is how many of the top results to show'''

    df = df.groupby(['A','B','C']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

    df = df.sort_values(by='count', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True).head(n)

    return df

common_data = common_cols(df,10)
```

Output of common_data(10 top results shown):

```
      A     B       C      count
0    0.00  0.00    0.00     96
1    0.00  1.00    0.00     25
2    0.14  0.86    0.00     19
3    0.13  0.87    0.00     17
4    0.00  0.72    0.28     17
5    0.00  0.89    0.11     16
6    0.01  0.84    0.15     16
7    0.03  0.97    0.00     15
8    0.35  0.65    0.00     15
9    0.13  0.79    0.08     14
```

Now, I would like to find combinations of the A B C rows, and count how many times they occurred.

For example lets say in the BASE df from row 1 to row 4:

the first set of combinations of the 3 columns (as told by dataframe(df) BEFORE using the common_cols function) are

```
# each of these rows are their own combination of values
       A    B     C
0    0.67  0.16  0.17
1    0.06  0.73  0.20
2    0.19  0.48  0.33
3    0.07  0.87  0.06
4    0.07  0.60  0.33
```

The above 5 rows (in order) would be counted as a pattern of combinations. It could be counted as a combination of 2 rows, 3 rows, 4 rows or more rows (if it is easy enough to do that is!)

If this pattern was found once(across the entire dataframe), it would output this pattern's count as 1. If it was found 10 times; the count would be 10.

Any ideas on how I can count the combinations found between consecutive rows?
Like from using the common_cols function, but as a 'combinations of combinations'?

The rows have to be in order for it to be a pattern. Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure if this is at all the right approach but maybe it helps: You could (iteratively) add columns to each row that holds lists of the values of the next N rows. For example, column N_5 for row 0 holds [row0, row1, row2, row3, row4]. Then, for each of these columns you can then concatenate all these columns with their respective count columns and do the group by function. Does that makes sense?

Comment: are you counting frequencies of the a,b,c values? if so a group and size should work.  what else do you need?

Comment: @JarroVGIT I am not sure, especially since this is my first time using groupby. Thanks for the help and idea :). Rick M's answer has what seems to be a working soloution

Comment: @GoldenLion The question was about counting the amount of times a consecutive pattern was found. For example, if in the data set the numbers (in order): 0.5, 0.25, 0.25 were found with 0.2, 0.8, 0.0 multiple times, I was looking for a pattern like that

Comment: use value_counts or Counter to get the unique counts for the combinations or groupby with size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used integers for this test dataframe, but if your `groupby` is working above this should also work for your data:

```
df_size = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'A' : (np.random.randint(20) for i in range(df_size)),
                     'B' : (np.random.randint(20) for i in range(df_size)),
                     'C' : (np.random.randint(20) for i in range(df_size)),
            })

print(df.head())
    A   B   C
0  12  12   5
1  19  12  12
2  14  11  15
3  11  14   8
4  13  16   2
```

The code below makes a list called `source` of the triplets (A, B, C) using `zip`. The `tmp` variable (a generator) is effectively a list that holds successively "shifted" copies of the source list, like `[source[0:], source[1:], source[2:]...]`

Finally, the `zip` interleaves the values from the lists in `tmp`, e.g., for `n=2` it would generate a list of
`[(source[0], source[1]), (source[1], source[2]), ... ]`

```
source = list(zip(df['A'],df['B'],df['C']))
n_consecutive = 3

tmp = ( source[i:] for i in range(n_consecutive) )
output = pd.Series(list(zip(*tmp)))
```

For this example, this is a series containing the counts of the triplet (A, B, C) values:

```
print(output.value_counts().head())
((6, 19, 14), (19, 12, 6), (13, 7, 10))    2
((2, 18, 12), (17, 2, 19), (7, 19, 19))    1
((10, 2, 3), (1, 18, 8), (3, 6, 19))       1
((16, 15, 14), (11, 2, 9), (14, 14, 8))    1
((3, 3, 7), (13, 9, 3), (18, 15, 6))       1
dtype: int64
```

Note that this will possibly double-count things depending on what you are looking for. For example, if the base df has three records in a row, and you're looking for patterns of 2 consecutive:

```
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 4)
```

In that case it will find `(1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 4)` twice.

Comment: Awesome man thank you very much. I am not sure about the double count but it seems to be working as it should, compared to the different code I was running to get the same result(my method was super clunky, yours is a godsend). Appreciated :)

Comment: Would you know how to implement a np.isclose() solution inside your code? Or is that something I would have to first do?

Comment: You're welcome! You could truncate the values to a desired level of precision before grouping and that would probably work, or maybe pre-binning the data with `np.histogramdd`... you might want to put up a separate question if that doesn't work. If you're good to go on this one, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers. Thanks, and take care.