# Pandas Number of Unique Values from 2 Fields

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the number of unique values that cover 2 fields. So for example, a typical example would be last name and first name. I have a data frame.

[image]

When I do the following, I just get the number of unique fields for each column, in this case, Last and First. Not a composite.

```
df[['Last Name','First Name']].nunique()
```

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268817/unique-combinations-of-values-in-selected-columns-in-pandas-data-frame-and-count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `value_counts()` for that:

```
df[['Last Name','First Name']].value_counts().size

3
```

For another example, if you start with this extended data frame that contains some dups:

```
  Last Name First Name
0     Smith       Bill
1   Johnson       Bill
2     Smith       John
3    Curtis       Tony
4    Taylor  Elizabeth
5     Smith       Bill
6   Johnson       Bill
7     Smith       Bill
```

Then `value_counts()` gives you the counts by unique composite last-first name:

```
df[['Last Name','First Name']].value_counts()

Last Name  First Name
Smith      Bill          3
Johnson    Bill          2
Curtis     Tony          1
Smith      John          1
Taylor     Elizabeth     1
```

Then the length of that frame will give you the number of unique composite last-first names:

```
df[['Last Name','First Name']].value_counts().size

5
```

Answer (score 3):

Groupby both columns first, and *then* use `nunique`

```
>>> df.groupby(['First Name', 'Last Name']).nunique()
```