# Pick unique values from the DataFrame - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
                      col1   col2     sum    value_1   value_2   value_3   value_4
timestamp       
2022-05-09 11:28:00    30     09       100      0         0        0         1
2022-05-09 11:28:01    30     11       105      0         0        1         0
2022-05-09 11:28:02    30     09       103      0         0        0         1
2022-05-09 11:28:03    50     11       109      0         1        1         0
2022-05-09 11:28:04    50     09       110      0         1        0         1
2022-05-09 11:28:05    50     09       101      0         1        0         1
```

From the above table, I want to extract the unique combinations of the values present in `col1` and `col2` ignoring the timestamp and the column `sum`. For example: from the above table, I want the following:

```
  col1   col2   value_1   value_2   value_3   value_4
   30     09      0         0        0         1
   30     11      0         0        1         0
   50     11      0         1        1         0
   50     09      0         1        0         1
```

The combinations (30,09), (30,11), (50,11) and (50,09) are unique. the values present in `value_1`, `value_2`, `value_3`, `value_4` are same for a particular combination.

Is there a way to obtain this?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268817/unique-combinations-of-values-in-selected-columns-in-pandas-data-frame-and-count

Comment: `groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4']`?

Comment: why not ```df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'])``` ?