# pandas unique values multiple columns different dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, unique

Similar to [pandas unique values multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977076/pandas-unique-values-multiple-columns) I want to count the number of unique values per column. However, as the dtypes differ I get the following error:
[image]

The data frame looks like
[image]
A `small[['TARGET', 'title']].apply(pd.Series.describe)` gives me the result, but only for the category types and I am unsure how to filter the index for only the last row with the unique values per column

Comment: Is `small[['TARGET','title']].apply(lambda x: np.unique(x).size)` what you're after?

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. Please feel free to write this as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply` and `np.unique` to grab the unique values in each column and take its `size`:

```
small[['TARGET','title']].apply(lambda x: np.unique(x).size)
```

Thanks!