# Identifying unique visitors from web log

Tags: python, logging, machine-learning, data-analysis, web-analytics

I am currently have a project analysing web logs of a website using machine learning. I am cleaning the data and want to identify unique ***visitors*** to this site.

I don't have much experience in dealing with web logs, but it is obvious to see that when a user visits, several files were retrieved (for example the records in column `cs.uri.stem` shown below).

My questions, how about when a user goes through several pages (like went to page B from a link in page A)? How can I know he's behaviours on this site?

Additionally, can anyone suggest any great python library that helps analysing web logs?

Much appreciated!!!

```
         date     time        s.ip cs.method cs.uri.stem                                                               cs.uri.query s.port cs.username         c.ip sc.status sc.substatus sc.win32.status time.taken device            os          browser
1  2014-08-05 00:00:03 10.130.0.12       GET /                                                                                    -     80           - 67.205.67.76       200            0               0       1391 Spider         Other   PingdomBot_1.4
2  2014-08-05 00:00:11 10.130.0.12       GET /about-the-hotel.aspx                                                                -     80           -  70.56.59.43       200            0               0       1194     PC Mac_OS_X_10.8     Firefox_31.0
3  2014-08-05 00:00:11 10.130.0.12       GET /~/media/Images/Hotel_ICON_revamp/about+us/a-hotel-unlike-any-others.ashx            -     80           -  70.56.59.43       200            0               0        976     PC Mac_OS_X_10.8     Firefox_31.0
4  2014-08-05 00:00:12 10.130.0.12       GET /~/media/Images/Hotel_ICON_revamp/about+us/0713-ExComTeam.ashx                       -     80           -  70.56.59.43       200            0               0       1620     PC Mac_OS_X_10.8     Firefox_31.0
5  2014-08-05 00:00:12 10.130.0.12       GET /~/media/Images/Hotel_ICON_revamp/about+us/icon/vivienne-tam.ashx                    -     80           -  70.56.59.43       200            0               0       1713     PC Mac_OS_X_10.8     Firefox_31.0
6  2014-08-05 00:00:12 10.130.0.12       GET /~/media/Images/Hotel_ICON_revamp/about+us/icon/william-lim.ashx                     -     80           -  70.56.59.43       200            0               0       2387     PC Mac_OS_X_10.8     Firefox_31.0
7  2014-08-05 00:00:14 10.130.0.12       GET /~/media/Images/Hotel_ICON_revamp/about+us/icon/barney-cheng.ashx                    -     80           -  70.56.59.43       200            0               0       2180     PC Mac_OS_X_10.8     Firefox_31.0
8  2014-08-05 00:00:14 10.130.0.12       GET /~/media/Images/Hotel_ICON_revamp/about+us/icon/tommy-li.ashx                        -     80           -  70.56.59.43       200            0               0       1146     PC Mac_OS_X_10.8     Firefox_31.0
9  2014-08-05 00:00:14 10.130.0.12       GET /~/media/Images/Hotel_ICON_revamp/about+us/icon/yang-rutherford.ashx                 -     80           -  70.56.59.43       200            0               0        869     PC Mac_OS_X_10.8     Firefox_31.0
10 2014-08-05 00:00:14 10.130.0.12       GET /~/media/Images/Hotel_ICON_revamp/about+us/icon/justin_wong_img1.ashx                -     80           -  70.56.59.43       200            0               0        845     PC Mac_OS_X_10.8     Firefox_31.0
```

Comment: You can specify them with IP-OS-Browser

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AdamLeo "how about when a user goes through several pages?" You can change your log and add referrer or  check a user IP, If one IP visited a page with special Os and browser, maybe he went to the second page from a link in the first page

Answer (score 1):

It may be a good idea to look at `pandas` library. Once you have loaded data using pandas (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21546823/477522)), it should be straight forward to find unique elements conditioned on one or multiple columns, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26977495/477522).