# Pandas Left Join results in more rows than the Left Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

I have more rows in the resultant left join than are in the left dataframe.

```
# Importing Pandas and changing it's call to pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

SalesDF = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Reports\SalesForAnalysis.csv")
print("This is the Sales shape")
print(SalesDF.shape)


CustInfoDF = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Cust.csv")

# This reassigns the df so that the rows with a NaN in the Account Number it  doesn't appear
CustInfoDF = CustInfoDF[CustInfoDF['Account Number'].notna()]


# Merges the two dataframes on SalesDF with "Cust Number" as the key
MergeDF = pd.merge(SalesDF, CustInfoDF, how="left", left_on="Cust Number", right_on="Account Number")

print("This is the Merge Shape ")
print(MergeDF.shape)

# Reduced the number of columns to the selected columns
CutDF = MergeDF[["Customer", "Invoice #", "E-mail Address", "Phone", "Clerk", "Total", "Date"]]

CutDF.drop_duplicates()

print("This is the Cut shape ")
print(CutDF.shape)
```

Here is the result after running the program

```
This is the Sales shape
(5347, 61)
This is the Merge Shape 
(6428, 83)
This is the Cut shape 
(6428, 7)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The CutDF should only have a max of 5347 rows. I have a drop_duplicates method in there but I still get the same results.

I saw this [pandas left join - why more results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002355/pandas-left-join-why-more-results)
and        [inner join/merge in pandas dataframe give more rows than left dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262134/inner-join-merge-in-pandas-dataframe-give-more-rows-than-left-dataframe) but I didn't really see a solution to this in these though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `SalesDF['Cust Number'].duplicated().any()`?

Comment: I am afraid that I do not understand the question. Could you rephrase please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you execute:

```
MergeDF = pd.merge(SalesDF, CustInfoDF, how="left", left_on="Cust Number", right_on="Account Number")
```

Can you do:

```
CustInfoDF = CustInfoDF.drop_duplicates(subset=["Account Number"])
```

I have a suspicion that your `CustInforDF` has multiple entries for each `Account Number`.

If this doesn't work, can you please post the sample data frames? Feel free to add/replace with dummy values as long as the code is replicable.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that there are redundant account numbers. I will give a more earnest effort to implement this when I have some time.

Comment: My new resultant message after adding ```CustInfoDF = CustInfoDF.drop_duplicates(on=["Account Number"])``` before my MergeDF is formed


```
This is the Sales shape
(5104, 62)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\PandasStuff\PyMailReport.py", line 18, in <module>
    CustInfoDF = CustInfoDF.drop_duplicates(on=["Account Number"])
TypeError: drop_duplicates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on'

Process finished with exit code 1```

Comment: Final Comment

Thank you Parmandeep, The issue is resolved. the "on=" wasn't necessary in the drop_duplicates code and that is what was throwing the program but now it seems to be working perfectly. 

Thank you very much

Comment: Ah yes, sorry the `on` should be `subset`. Just updating in case people use this in the future.