# Get unique pairs of columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, unique, multiple-columns

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks as follows:

```
name1   country1    name2   country2
A       GER         B       USA
C       GER         E       GER
D       GER         Y       AUS
E       GER         A       USA
```

I want to get a new dataframe with two columns `name` and `country` that contains the unique pairs of `(name1, country1)` and `(name2,country2)`.

The expected result should look like this:

```
name    country 
A       GER     
C       GER     
D       GER     
E       GER     
B       USA
A       USA
Y       AUS
```

I have found something similar for single columns [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977076/pandas-unique-values-multiple-columns). However, I do not know how to transform this solution to my problem, that is, pairs of columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First filter columns by [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), transpose, flatten values and create new `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
a = df.filter(like='name').values.T.ravel()
b = df.filter(like='country').values.T.ravel()
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':a, 'country':b}, columns=['name','country'])
print (df)
  name country
0    A     GER
1    C     GER
2    D     GER
3    E     GER
4    B     USA
5    E     GER
6    Y     AUS
7    A     USA
```

Another solution with undocumented function `lreshape`:

```
df = pd.lreshape(df, {'name':['name1','name2'],
                      'country':['country1','country2']})
print (df)
  name country
0    A     GER
1    C     GER
2    D     GER
3    E     GER
4    B     USA
5    E     GER
6    Y     AUS
7    A     USA
```

---

And last for unique pairs use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print (df)
  name country
0    A     GER
1    C     GER
2    D     GER
3    E     GER
4    B     USA
6    Y     AUS
7    A     USA
```

Comment: which solution is better?

Comment: First is faster I think