# How to categorize two categories in one dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, categories

I have one pd including two categorical columns with 150 categories. May be a value in column `A` is not appeared in Column `B`. For example

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('bbaba'),  'B':list('cccaa')})
a['A'] = a['A'].astype('category')
a['B'] = a['B'].astype('category')
```

The output is

```
Out[217]: 
   A  B
0  b  c
1  b  c
2  a  c
3  b  a
4  a  a
```

And also

```
cat_columns = a.select_dtypes(['category']).columns
a[cat_columns] = a[cat_columns].apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)
a
```

The output is

```
Out[220]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  0  1
3  1  0
4  0  0
```

My problem is that in column `A`, the `b` is considered as `1`, but in column `B`, the `c` is considered as `1`. However, I want something like this:

```
Out[220]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  0  2
3  1  0
4  0  0
```

which `2` is considered as `c`.

Please note that I have 150 different labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`pd.Categorical()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) you can specify a list of categories:

```
In [44]: cats = a[['A','B']].stack().sort_values().unique()

In [45]: cats
Out[45]: array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)

In [46]: a['A'] = pd.Categorical(a['A'], categories=cats)

In [47]: a['B'] = pd.Categorical(a['B'], categories=cats)

In [48]: a[cat_columns] = a[cat_columns].apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)

In [49]: a
Out[49]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  0  2
3  1  0
4  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pd.factorize` all at once.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    pd.factorize(a.values.ravel())[0].reshape(a.shape),
    a.index, a.columns
)

   A  B
0  0  1
1  0  1
2  2  1
3  0  2
4  2  2
```

---

Or if you wanted to factorize by sorted category value, use the `sort=True` argument

```
pd.DataFrame(
    pd.factorize(a.values.ravel(), True)[0].reshape(a.shape),
    a.index, a.columns
)

   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  0  2
3  1  0
4  0  0
```

---

Or equivalently with `np.unique`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.unique(a.values.ravel(), return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(a.shape),
    a.index, a.columns
)

   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  0  2
3  1  0
4  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are *only* interested in converting to categorical codes and being able to access the mapping via a dictionary, [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) may be more convenient.

Algorithm for getting unique values across columns [via @AlexRiley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26977495/9209546).

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('bbaba'),  'B':list('cccaa')})

fact = dict(zip(*pd.factorize(pd.unique(a[['A', 'B']].values.ravel('K')))[::-1]))

b = a.applymap(fact.get)
```

Result:

```
   A  B
0  0  2
1  0  2
2  1  2
3  0  1
4  1  1
```