# Efficient way of converting a numpy array of 2 dimensions into a list with no duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I want to extract the values from two different columns of a pandas dataframe, put them in a list with no duplicate values.

I have tried the following:

```
arr = df[['column1', 'column2']].values
thelist= []
    for ix, iy in np.ndindex(arr.shape):
        if arr[ix, iy] not in thelist:
            thelist.append(edges[ix, iy])
```

This works but it is taking too long. The dataframe contains around 30 million rows.

Example:

```
  column1 column2 
1   adr1   adr2   
2   adr1   adr2   
3   adr3   adr4   
4   adr4   adr5
```

Should generate the list with the values:

`[adr1, adr2, adr3, adr4, adr5]`

Can you please help me find a more efficient way of doing this, considering that the dataframe contains 30 million rows.

Comment: `np.unique(df.values)`. The default is to flatten arrays, so this does exactly what you want.

Comment: `list(np.unique(df.to_numpy())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas unique values multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977076/pandas-unique-values-multiple-columns)

Comment: @ALollz is it normal that the contiguous order is not preserved? I need it to be contiguous.

Comment: @alejo then try `pd.unique(df.values.ravel())`. `pd.unique` preserves order, while `np.unique` sorts

Answer (score 2):

@ALollz gave a right answer. I'll extend from there. To convert into list as expected just use `list(np.unique(df.values))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `np.unique(df)` (maybe this is the shortest version).

Formally, the first parameter of `np.unique` should be an *array_like* object,
but as I checked, you can also pass just a *DataFrame*.

Of course, if you want just plain *list* not a *ndarray*, write
`np.unique(df).tolist()`.

## Edit following your comment

If you want the list **unique** but in the **order of appearance**, write:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,1))[0].drop_duplicates().tolist()
```

Operation order:

- `reshape` changes the source array into a single column.
- Then a *DataFrame* is created, with default column name = `0`.
- Then `[0]` takes just this (the only) column.
- `drop_duplicates` acts exactly what the name says.
- And the last step: `tolist` converts to a plain *list*.

Comment: Thanks @Valdi_Bo, is it normal that the contiguous order is not preserved? I need it to be contiguous.

Comment: Do you mean the *order of appearance* in the source table? The documentation states that if no *axis* has been given, then the input array is flattened (not sure about the order). Another step when the order can be changed is the *np.unique* function itself. It seems that the result has been sorted.