# Delete rows with overlapping items

Tags: python, pandas, rows

I have a data frame which looks like the below:

```html
Customer 1  Customer 2  Customer 3
A               B            C
B               C            D 
C               D            E
D               E            F
E               F            G
```

There are customers coming to a store continuously. I want to create a row of the first 3 customers coming in the store in an hour. As the customers keep coming in continuously, it keeps taking group 3 and making rows. Though I do not want to form strict hour lining like 1-2, 2-3, etc.

I just want if customer B and C are covered in row 1, they should not be counted in row 2.
I want to delete rows that have overlapping items and only keep the unique ones.
So my expected output would be:

```html
Customer 1  Customer 2  Customer 3
A               B            C
D               E            F
G
```

How to achieve this, please help.
Thanks

Comment: I wonder why are you using pandas here, regardless what about the G?

Comment: That would be taken in row number 3 with other customers

Comment: ok so shouldn't there be another row in the required output but then it would repeat.

Comment: yes there should be 3rd row, added in edit

Comment: does flattened unique values as a list work for you or do you want in the exact same format as in the question?

Comment: For the group of 3 columns, I want unique values as a group. One customer would be counted in only 1 row. How to use flattened unique values?

Comment: @zsh-18 I have added an approach to work with the unique values and convert them back to groups of 3.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is my take on this, NOT ready yet but should point you in the right direction any edits are welcome

First, let's set up the data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "Customer 1": ["A", "B","C","D", "E"],
    "Customer 2": [ "B","C","D", "E", "F"],
    "Customer 3": ["C","D", "E", "F", "G"],
})
```

Working on NumPy will be much better so let's create a variable with a NumPy 2d array

```
df_np = df.values

df_np.flatten()[:6] # This will flatten the list and will only take the first 6 items to be able to reshape it later

np.unique(df_np) # Removes all duplicates so we will be only left with data shape that can be rebuilt into a DataFrame
```

Now let's reshape it back to the original shape

```
np.reshape(c, (-1, 3))
```

You can now rebuild the dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(data=c, columns=df.columns)
```

I couldn't find a way to take care of the G, and as I've said before not a complete solution so any edits are welcome

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

First we get all the [unique values across rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977076/pandas-unique-values-multiple-columns). Group the unique values `numpy` array together taking 3 at a time as requested and pad the remaining unfilled columns with `invalid` values and then convert back to dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Customer 1" : ["A","B","C","D","E"],
                  "Customer 2" : ["B","C","D","E","F"],
                  "Customer 3" : ["C","D","E","F","G"]})



unique_vals = pd.unique(df[['Customer 1', 'Customer 2', 'Customer 3']].values.ravel('K'))

new_shape = unique_vals.size + 3 - unique_vals.size % 3

new_df_source = np.full(new_shape, fill_value = "invalid")

new_df_source.flat[:unique_vals.size] = unique_vals

new_df_source = new_df_source.reshape(-1,3)
output_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df_source, columns=df.columns)
```

**Result:**

```
  Customer 1 Customer 2 Customer 3
0          A          B          C
1          D          E          F
2          G    invalid    invalid
```

**Caveat:** The rows in `output_df` may not be present at all in input `df` since we are looking at the unique values and grouping back together, though we are still maintaining relative order of unique values.